# Something like float left but

Tags: css

I have undifined number 3 different size, i want to put them float like the example but without empty spaces.

https://jsfiddle.net/5mtrz6m8/

html : `<ul id="showcase"></ul>`

css :

```
#showcase{
  width: 500px;
}

#showcase li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#showcase li.large {
  width: 66%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

#showcase li.tiny {
  width: 33%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: green;
}

#showcase li.portrait {
  width: 33%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

simulated data :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    recursive(1);
});

function recursive(i){
  if (Number(i) < 40){          
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      var vignette = jQuery("<li><div></div></li>");

      switch(rand) {
      case 1:
          vignette.addClass("large");
          break;
      case 2:
          vignette.addClass("tiny");
          break;
      case 3:
          vignette.addClass("portrait");
          break;
      default:
          vignette.addClass("tiny");
          break;
      }

            vignette.appendTo("#showcase");
      setTimeout(recursive(Number(i)+1),(Math.random() * 10))
  }
};
```

I wish to fill empty spaces with the first following element that can enter in space.

Is it possible in pure css ?

Comment: [Masonry layout in CSS](https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a#.8vi83pss8) will likely be useful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're attempting to do is traditionally handled by javascript, usually referred to as masonry (using a library like [this one](http://masonry.desandro.com/))

If you want to achieve the effect with pure CSS and don't need to support old browsers, I'd look into using the [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) syntax

Comment: Thx for answer, i'll take a look on Flexbox.
I also found [link](http://suprb.com/apps/nested/) this with JS, it working well.

Comment: Nice, that's a new one to me, seems pretty simple to work with. The style of the animation on rearrange is nice too